# Kusto to Osquery translator?

Tags: detection, end-points, nosql

[Osquery](https://osquery.io/) is a great open standard for collecting data from endpoints, using SQL syntax.

[Kusto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet) is a new Microsoft language for collecting data from Windows endpoints, using syntax which is almost--but not entirely--unlike SQL.

Microsoft is publishing [threat hunting guidance in Kusto](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2022/08/24/magicweb-nobeliums-post-compromise-trick-to-authenticate-as-anyone/).

Is there any easy way to translate threat hunting queries that are published in Kusto into an Osquery compatible form?